# How can I get SU permission on an android device after I whiped all data?

Tags: android, adb

I followed along with a guide on installing lineageOS on my OnePlus 5. I had the phone set up, with OEM and debugger permissions. I also installed TWRP. After the initial setup I was prompted to wipe the phone system and cache to clear some errors I was having as that seemed the solution. In doing so I fixed my errors, however, I also lost the lineageOS I had on my phone previously and everything else.

I still have TWRP installed interestingly enough, however, I can't go into fastboot mode to flash a new lineageOS from my computer. I want to upload the lineageOS to the phone with the "ADB push" command however that does not work as it seems to lack privileges and the error it gives is "could not create file: No such file found" when I try to push the lineageOS .zip file onto the /sdcard.

When I try to go into "ADB shell" and change the permissions to the /sdcard, I get an error saying SU is not present or something to that degree.

Comment: Wrong forum, more for programming questions. Good luck though.

Comment: adb is a tool for android developers ... if I use it for programming or not is irrelevant to the question